# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined with correct import being available

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using `react-router` and have seen the other questions asked already. May be I am blind or this may be a valid issue.

`index.js` has

```
const Root = () => (
    <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            <div>
                <Route path="/" component={App}/>
                <Route path="/menu" component={Menu}/>
                <Route path="/summary" component={Summary}/>
                <Route path="/menuDetail/:id" component={MenuDetail}/>
                <Redirect from="/" to="/summary"/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
);
```

`MenuDetail.js` looks like

```
import React from 'react';

const MenuDetail = ({match}) => (
    <div>
        <h3>Menu Id: {match.params.id}</h3>
    </div>
);

export default MenuDetail;
```

in `SpicyMenu.js` I do

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
class SpicyMenuItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.fetchMenuItem = this.fetchMenuItem.bind(this);
    }

    fetchMenuItem(menuId) {
        return () => {
            console.log("fetching menu with id: " + menuId);
            browserHistory.push('/menuDetail/' + menuId);
        }

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ListItem onClick={this.fetchMenuItem(this.props.id)}>
                <Grid fluid>
                    <Row center="lg" style={RowItemStyle}>
                        <Col xs={3} sm={3} lg={2}><Avatar src={this.props.image}/></Col>
                        <Col xs={6} sm={6} lg={4}>{this.props.name}</Col>
                        <Col xs={3} sm={3} lg={2}>{this.props.price}</Col>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
            </ListItem>
        );
    }
}
```

But when I run this and click on a `ListItem`, it gives me the following

```
SpicyMenu.js:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Object.onClick (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:78878:45)
    at EnhancedButton._this.handleClick (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42799:22)
    at Object.ReactErrorUtils.invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17230:17)
    at executeDispatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17013:22)
    at Object.executeDispatchesInOrder (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17036:6)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16424:23)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16435:11)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at forEachAccumulated (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17333:10)
    at Object.processEventQueue (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:16638:8)
    at runEventQueueInBatch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24260:19)
    at Object.handleTopLevel [as _handleTopLevel] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24271:6)
    at handleTopLevelImpl (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29372:25)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:19844:21)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29287:27)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18463:28)
    at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29447:21)
```

The specific commit for this change is https://github.com/hhimanshu/spicyveggie/commit/0532b9d7ea16d7f7f672973bedcf4109f4aa4dcf
and the complete code is available at https://github.com/hhimanshu/spicyveggie/tree/menu_detail

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4640 might help try importing from lib

Comment: another issue can be  <ListItem onClick={this.fetchMenuItem(this.props.id)}>. it should be :  <ListItem onClick={()=>this.fetchMenuItem(this.props.id)}>

Comment: @Ved, this is not needed since my `onClick` returns a function.

Comment: @VinodLouis, I get `Cannot find module "react-router/es/browserHistory"`

Answer (score 0):

You're using react-router v4 and it doesn't support anymore using `browserHistory` like this. You can access `history` from your route component's (SpicyMenuItem) props and you can call `push` method of it like this.

```
props.history.push('/menuDetail/' + menuId);
```

Also you don't need provid `browserHistory` when you define `<Router>`. Use new [`<BrowserRouter>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) instead.

Comment: I tried `this.props.history.push('/menuDetail/' + menuId);` since this is a `class Component`, but the error is still the same.

Comment: I just noticed that your SpicyMenuItem isn't a route component. So you might need to wrap it using `withRouter` to access `history` through props.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: Yes, I was exactly looking at that in the documentation right now

Answer (score 0):

My `Component` is not a `Router` Component, so I had to wrap it with `withRouter` API. The solution looks like

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
class SpicyMenu extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            foodItems: foodItems
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <List>
                {this.state.foodItems.map(foodItem => <SpicyMenuItemWithRouter key={foodItem.id} {...foodItem}/>)}
            </List>

        );
    }
}
const SpicyMenuItemWithRouter = withRouter(SpicyMenuItem);
```

That fixed the issue. Thanks everyone for the help